# How to set random colors and button rounded at the same time?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-button

I'm trying to make buttons rounded, random background color? When I tried the code below, the button isn't rounded.

Here is the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newtestament);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutnew);
    String[] values = { "Matthai", "Marka", "Luka", "Johan",
            "Sawltak Tangthu", "Rom Laikhak", "Korin Masa", "Korin Nihna",
            "Galati", "Efesa", "Filippi", "Kolose", "Thesalonika Masa",
            "Thesalonika Nihna", "Timoti Masa", "Timoti Nihna", "Titus",
            "Filemon", "Hebru", "James", "Peter Masa", "Peter Nihna",
            "Johan Masa", "Johan Nihna", "Johan Thumna", "Jude",
            "Maangmuhna" };
    Button[] b = new Button[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i] = new Button(this);
    }
    int[] btnColor = { 0xAAe60038, 0xAA9142d6, 0xAAf07b04, 0xAA1515ff,
            0xAA23699e, 0xAA0a71ff, 0xAA3e3d39, 0xAA00b323, 0xAA754e45,
            0xAAfa061e, 0xAAe66d2d, 0xAAff00ff };
    // calling random
    Random random = new Random();
    // ramdomizing a color
    int c = btnColor[random.nextInt(btnColor.length)];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

        // applying button rounded xml style
        b[i].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.round));
        // setting randomized color
        b[i].setBackgroundColor(c);
        // layout
        LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        // margin
        ((MarginLayoutParams) params).setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        // padding
        b[i].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        // text color
        b[i].setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        // text
        b[i].setText(values[i]);
        // text size
        b[i].setTextSize(18);
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext()
                .getAssets(), "UBUNTU-R.TTF");
        b[i].setTypeface(face);
        layout.addView(b[i], params);

    }

}
```

Here is round.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color -->
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
    </shape>
```

I think  the problems are setBackgroundDrawable, setBackgroundColor and romdomizing. What additional codes are needed? ??? 
 **Update**:How to edit round.xml to make the button rounded?

Answer (score 3):

**You are setting button background as drawable and then the color also**. So **statements are executed sequentially**. So in the end your button should have a background color set.
So try commenting one of them and run the code again.

```
    b[i].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.round));
    // set background drawable
    // first your background drawable will be set
    b[i].setBackgroundColor(c);
    //set background color.
```

bkg.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
<item  android:state_focused="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>    
<stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#0FECFF" /><!-- #330000FF #ffffffff -->

<padding android:left="5dp"
         android:top="5dp"
         android:right="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/> 
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#FF1A47"/>    
<stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#0FECFF"/>
<padding android:left="5dp"
         android:top="5dp"
         android:right="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/> 
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>

  b[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bkg);
```

Snap Shot

[image]

Edit:

```
  int colors []= {Color.RED, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN};
  Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        b[i].setBackgroundColor(colors[r.nextInt(3)]);
    }
```

Comment: you have to create a folder drawable under res/drawable and put all your xmls above in the drawable folder

Comment: randomizing colors is a important matter. HOw can you solive it? :(

Comment: can you see the snap shot attached. Just change the colors in normal. xml and pressed.xml. Button when not pressed looks like the snap shot. When pressed the background color changes and border remains the same. When user lifts the finger it goes back to default state.

Comment: thanks for you rhelp. but i want to make buttons fancy. to make randomize colors. how to code or repair the code?

Comment: check the edited answer. But you can't make your buttons round and set random color at the same time. I wish someone has a better solution. But i do not know how to do button round and set random color at the same time. Also if the colors are more then chances of repeating the same color decreases.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer doesn't set random color and button rounded at the same time. :)

Comment: nope not possible not with the method you used above. However i do not know of a alternative. You cannot edit the resources in xml at run time.

Answer (score 2):

look at [Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)   . `view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable)`  and `b[i].setBackgroundColor(c);` you can't use both at a time. it will take to effect last one only.

Comment: what does this answer exactly mean? I 'm just beginner. please explain me clearly. :-(

Comment: instead of using this setBackgroundDrawable, just use setBackgroundResource();

Comment: no need to edit your xml's just do what i said in above line.

Comment: ramdomizing colors is an important matter,too. how can you solve it?Sir :( replacing the function doesn't work.